# Why Android Studio can not compile

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am attempting to compile my project in Andriod Studio; however, it consistently provides me with the following error:

> **Error**:duplicate files during packaging of **APK** `E:\Androidstdio\MyApplication\PTTTalk\build\outputs\apk\PTTTalk-debug-unaligned.apk`

If I ignore these within my `build.gradle`, it still doesn't compile.

> E:\Androidstdio\MyApplication\PTTTalk\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\MyApplication\androidngnstack\unspecified\jni\armeabi-v7a\libijkffmpeg.so    Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK E:\Androidstdio\MyApplication\PTTTalk\build\outputs\apk\PTTTalk-debug-unaligned.apk    Path in archive: lib/armeabi-v7a/libijkffmpeg.so    Origin 1: E:\Androidstdio\MyApplication\PTTTalk\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\libmediastream-release\jni\armeabi-v7a\libijkffmpeg.so    You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:    android {        packagingOptions {            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libijkffmpeg.so'        }    }    Error:Execution failed for task ':PTTTalk:packageDebug'.            > Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libijkffmpeg.so    File 1: E:\Androidstdio\MyApplication\PTTTalk\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\libmediastream-release\jni\armeabi-v7a\libijkffmpeg.so    File 2: E:\Androidstdio\MyApplication\PTTTalk\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\MyApplication\androidngnstack\unspecified\jni\armeabi-v7a\libijkffmpeg.so

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with the compiler?

Comment: Can u post what are all files there in lib folder?

Comment: Fixed formatting and reworded to clarify

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file, your Android.mk (if you have one), and your project structure. libijkffmpeg.so is included from two locations: libmediastream-release\jni\armeabi-v7a\libijkffmpeg.so and androidngnstack\unspecified\jni\armeabi-v7a\libijkffmpeg.so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a native library duplicated in your package, namely libijkffmpeg.so.
You could try to exclude one of the origins with the packagingOptions of gradle.

Try to add this in the gradle.build file of your project:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libijkffmpeg.so'
}
```

Comment: handsome man  I try to this in the Gradle.build file but as usual fail